# How to delete / remove a 500G cloud station database

Tags: disk-space

I have 250M of data on cloud station that is sync'ed between severil computers.
When I checked the database size it reported it was 500G!
I have deleted versions, removed deleted files, but still he database is 500G.
How can I manually remove the database and allow cloud station to recreate it?
Why is the database reported as being so large?
We're is the database file stored?
How do I see the database file?

DS212J
DS716 + Ii

Regards
Keith